# Correct views hook to alter contextual filter

Tags: 8, views

I am trying to find the correct views hook to alter/add a contextual filter to a views block that's being rendered in a template. (Using drupal_view and the twig tweaks module).

The view is setup to accept a contextual filter that is provided in the URL by default. It works great on that page, however it's been requested that the view also display on a sub-page of this main page, in where the URL does not contain the contextual filter. Therefore, I am trying to find a views hook that I can reliably attach the contextual filter to and have it work every page load.

I have tried using `hook_views_pre_view()`, however this appears to only work once between cache clears, as if I clear cache it works, then as soon as I refresh the page it stops working again until another cache clear.

Is there a way I can do this from a hook? The way the child-page is structured, I can't easily get it from the template to pass it into drupal_view() as an argument.

The current code I am using is:

```
function item_types_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
    if ($view->id() == 'existing_copies') {

        $parameters = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameters();
        $imcid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('imcid');

        $entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('item_type')->load($imcid);

        if ($entity->bundle() == 'book_copy') {
            $main_record = $entity->field_book_main_record->getString();
        }
        elseif ($entity->bundle() == 'book_master_copy') {
            $main_record = $entity->field_master_copy_book_mr->getString();
        }

        $args = [$main_record];
    }
}
```

Which like I said, works great immediately after a cache clear, but no longer works after the page is refreshed.

Comment: There's another approach too: you can add a custom default argument plugin (the things which power _Content ID from URL_, _Raw value from URL_, etc). See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Plugin%21views%21argument_default%21Node.php/class/Node/8.9.x and https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21argument_default%21Raw.php/class/Raw/8.9.x for examples

Comment: Hmm, can I make this only available on a specific view? Id hate to implement thials globally and somebody not familiar with views using it and breaking stuff on existing views.

Comment: Well there goes my argument about reusability anyway ;) There probably will be a way to make it work for just one view, but that would probably involve another hook and the reason for using a plugin would kind of been lost. For your current code would you not just need to add `$view->setArguments($args);`?

Comment: Ignore that, stupid question, I read the post properly. Sounds like you just need to add a cache context somewhere

Comment: I don't have anywhere to attach that. The pre_view hook appears to be cached, so it doesn't update changes, at least if it's supposed to its not.

Comment: As far as cache goes, I have views cache disabled, and also this specific views cache off so I think its just that the hook isn't called consistently

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use achieved what I wanted by using `hook_views_pre_build()` as below

```
hook_views_pre_build(ViewExecutable $view) {
  $args[0] = '1234';

  $view->addArguments($args);
}
```

Comment: Better suited for adding/reading arguments is [hook_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/9.0.x).